# Unix: filtering CSV columns according to external file

Tags: unix, awk

I am working on a large csv file (millions of rows and 80 thousand columns). I want to extract and save in a new file all rows and only those columns that are listed in an external text file. For instance:

#### Source data file

```
id,snp1,snp2,snp3,snp4,snp5,snp6,snp7,snp8,snp9,snp10
sampl1,AA,BB,AB,BB,AA,AA,AB,BB,BB,BB
sampl2,AA,BB,BB,BB,AB,AA,AB,BB,BB,BB
sampl3,AA,BB,AB,BB,BB,AA,AA,BB,BB,BB
sampl4,AA,BB,AA,BB,AB,AA,BB,BB,BB,BB
sampl5,AA,BB,AB,BB,AB,AA,AA,BB,BB,BB
sampl6,AA,BB,AB,BB,BB,AA,AB,BB,BB,BB
sampl7,AA,BB,BB,AB,AB,AA,AB,BB,BB,BB
```

#### External file with list of columns to keep-

```
snp3
snp6
snp7
snp10
```

#### Resulting (new) file

```
id,snp3,snp6,snp7,snp10
sampl1,AB,AA,AB,BB
sampl2,BB,AA,AB,BB
sampl3,AB,AA,AA,BB
sampl4,AA,AA,BB,BB
sampl5,AB,AA,AA,BB
sampl6,AB,AA,AB,BB
sampl7,BB,AA,AB,BB
```

Is there an efficient approach to do that using awk?

Comment: What have you tried?  What have you considered?  It looks eminently doable and not very hard.  What should happen if the list of columns includes names that aren't found in the list of columns in line 1 of the main data file?  Does the code need to worry about quotes around and spaces or commas within column names?

Comment: Thank you. I did not know how to extend the approach of extracting specific columns (awk -F "\"*,\"*" '{print $1,$3}' myfile.csv) to read from an external file. I am beginner on unix. If the list of columns includes names that are not in the external list, the resulting data file should include only the matches, which is the result from using solution provided by @karafka.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a non-awk solution

```
$ cut -d, -f1,$(grep -Ff columns <(sed 1q file | tr ',' '\n' | nl -w1) | cut -f1 | paste -sd,) file

id,snp3,snp6,snp7,snp10
sampl1,AB,AA,AB,BB
sampl2,BB,AA,AB,BB
sampl3,AB,AA,AA,BB
sampl4,AA,AA,BB,BB
sampl5,AB,AA,AA,BB
sampl6,AB,AA,AB,BB
sampl7,BB,AA,AB,BB
```

or

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {cols[$1]; next}
       FNR==1  {for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) if($i in cols) colin[i]}
               {line=$1;
                for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if(i in colin) line=line FS $i; 
                print line}' columns FS=, file

id,snp3,snp6,snp7,snp10
sampl1,AB,AA,AB,BB
sampl2,BB,AA,AB,BB
sampl3,AB,AA,AA,BB
sampl4,AA,AA,BB,BB
sampl5,AB,AA,AA,BB
sampl6,AB,AA,AB,BB
sampl7,BB,AA,AB,BB
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @karafka. It works perfectly considering also the mismatches between initial and external list of columns to keep.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommand using csvkit. Csvkit it build for that job, and work properly if some of data are strings in double quote contaning ','.

Install :

```
sudo apt python3-csvkit
```

Use

```
 csvcut source.csv -c  $(cat cols.txt | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/,$//')
```

The -c option take the names of the columns, tr is used to replace the character '\n' by a ','. And since, we don't want our arguments to finish by a ',' we use sed to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
NR==FNR {
    list["id"]
    list[$0]
    next
}
FNR==1 {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        if ($i in list) {
            f[++nf] = i
        }
    }
}
{
    for (i=1; i<=nf; i++) {
        printf "%s%s", $(f[i]), (i<nf ? OFS : ORS)
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk list file
id,snp3,snp6,snp7,snp10
sampl1,AB,AA,AB,BB
sampl2,BB,AA,AB,BB
sampl3,AB,AA,AA,BB
sampl4,AA,AA,BB,BB
sampl5,AB,AA,AA,BB
sampl6,AB,AA,AB,BB
sampl7,BB,AA,AB,BB
```